# VS2008 debugger and kernel32.dll

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, kernel32

I've been just debugging a process (in C++/windows) which uses "GetThreadContext" which is in kernel32.dll.
I noticed that I could get it's address with

```
unsigned long address = (unsigned long)(&GetThreadContext);
```

but when I looked at the loaded modules tab - I saw that the symbols for kernel32.dll were not loaded!
How did the VS2008 know the address of "GetThreadContext"?
And  how can I do it myself without having the PDBs?
thanks :)

Comment: GetProcAddr(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/64tkc9y5%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) maybe? I've never used it, so I'm not completely sure about this.

Comment: Please dont ship PDBs with your product.

Comment: Oh, and are there API functions to list the exported methods of a DLL?

Comment: You can use command line `dumpbin /exports myname.dll` to get that info.

Comment: I want to do it through code :)

Comment: You need `dbghelp.dll` then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

This works for the same reason that

```
GetThreadContext(hThread, lpContext);
```

works.  Named functions used in your code must be resolved at link-time, or the link would fail.  Whether you are taking their address using `&` or calling them does not matter.  At runtime, the DLL is loaded and the function name then resolves to a specific address in the process.

PDB files are used only to provide enhanced symbolic information during debugging.  Normally, they are not used at runtime.

[I can't help thinking I'm missing something about this question.  Tell me if this is not your problem.]

Comment: I think it's confusing what the compiler needs vs. how the debugger resolves symbols. Although in both cases you will still get the correct value without symbols from the .dll.